# How to denote the induced map onto the image?

Tags: functions, soft-question, notation

Given a (continuous) map $f:X\rightarrow Y$,
I am looking for an evident notation for the induced map onto its image, denoted by $e$ in this diagram:

[image: Universal property of the image]
[Image by Noix07](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=56238559)
– Own work, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)

I want to be able to write something like this, without having to explain the notation:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map.
>   Consider $\mathbf{?}:X\rightarrow\operatorname{im}f$.
>   Then $\mathbf{?}$ is …

It could be something similar to $\overline{f}$ or $\tilde{f}$, but I usually preserve these for quotients, liftings etc.

*I would prefer answers that also give reference to work where you have seen this notation.*